# Как настроить Kodachi Linux persistent?

Tags: linux, kodachi-linux

Вчера я услышал об очень интересном дистрибутиве Linux на основе Debian 64bit под названием Kodachi. Когда я запустил его со своего USB-накопителя, я увидел стандартные режимы, такие как: `live, persistence, install, fail-safe`.
И вся тема моего вопроса - «Как создать эту `persistence`?».

До этого, я также работал с дистрибутивом на основе Debian под названием Kali Linux. Я думаю, что он может быть создан путем создания нового раздела файловой системы `ext4` с именем `persistence` и смонтирован следующими командами:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/sdc3
mount /dev/sdc3 /mnt/sdc3
echo "/ union" > /mnt/sdc3/persistence.conf
umount /dev/sdc3
```

[это просто мой пример из того, как я его создал на Kali]
Я думаю, что это близко к этому примеру, но я не уверен. Так что, кто знает помогите пожалуйста. Как его создать на Kodachi?

Comment: Translate on Russian, please.